# Android shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Can anyone tell me if the memory of the phone is full,(the internal memory, because i am guessing that is where the `shared preferences` are saved by default, no?) and my app tries to write some `shared preference` values (`SharedPreferences class`), what happens then? Can i/should i keep this in mind when using shared preferences, or what?

Comment: I just think when the phone memory is full, all apps work badly, not only mine. So the system will alert the user. I think I won't worry about that...

Comment: I guess in that case , your application will not even start, because for the Heap Memory, there has to be some free Memory.

Comment: @Android but there should be reserved parts of memory to prevent total failure (right?)

Comment: means ? not getting your point.

Comment: @Android: Andrei is not talking about RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putString("name", "AndroDev");
edit.commit();
```

`commit` will finally writes the values in sharedpreference and if it fails to do so, it returns false. So in your case, it will return **false**. So you can check this value in your scenario.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what i was looking for. It's a simple solution, can't imagine how i didn't think about it :) Thanks.

Comment: I have a follow-up: What should the programmer do in this scenario? alert the user and crash the app? I mean,crash if the preferences to be saved are vital (otherwise just alert?). Are there any good practices here?

Comment: My personal (beginner) advice would be to see if you can store the info on an external card, if it exists or otherwise announce the user there is no more room to save the information and ask him to delete something. :) Again, this is my own personal idea on how to get about doing it.